# Slide div from minus top value

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm a beginner to jquery. I want to make a simple fadeindown when I click a button, but from the above the screen,e.g. minus top value. But what I get is only sliding in the page, not from above. And it only works once when I load the html. After that, opacity is the only one working. Here's the sample code:

```
#Page {
  opacity: 0;
  width:70%;
  min-height: 300px;
  background:white;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position:relative;
  padding:20px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

in `document.ready()`, when I load the html

```
$("#Page").position().top=$("#Page").outerHeight()*-1;
$("#Page").animate({top:$(".row").outerHeight(),opacity:'1'},1500);
```

and the `.click` function

```
$("#Page").css('opacity','0');
$("#Page").position().top=$("#Page").outerHeight()*-1;
$("#Page").animate({top:$(".row").outerHeight(),opacity:'1'},1500);
```

it seems only in `document.ready` that my fadeindown works. Anyone know the reason?

N.B: I try it only in my browser,not hosting it,not even at localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use css:

```
#Page {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

.hidden-element {
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

And then JQuery to hide element:

```
$("#Page").addClass('hidden-element');
```

And to show:

```
$("#Page").removeClass('hidden-element');
```

Comment: is there any different if I use a new class with opacity 1,and  #Page starting with opacity 0? I have tried that before using .animate. is there any difference?

Comment: sure, you can swap states for your needs and make #Page opacity:0, top:-100px, and create class with opacity: 1, top: 0. It depends on what state you need by default.